# Neither forceCommunity:routeChange or aura:locationChange cannot detect the URL change with history.replaceState

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, url, lightning-events, custom-url

We have a use case where a lightning component built in LWC, should trigger a URL change.

We're handling that with the `history.replaceState` method(*note that we encountered the same problem with `history.pushState`*).

In the other hand, upon a URL change an Aura Component should rerender/reflect this change.

**Problem**:

Neither of the standard events [`forceCommunity:routeChange`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:routeChange/documentation) or [`aura:locationChange`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:locationChange/documentation) are able to pickup the URL change.

Is this a bug or these events are not supposed to pickup such kind of URL change?

**Reproducing the problem:**

In order to reproduce this scenario I've built a basic demo app, that can be found & deployed from this [repo](https://github.com/endrit-sino-liqid/lightning-url-change-detection).

Comment: I think that is because the `pushState` never causes a hashchange event to be fired and I belive the two salesforce events you have mentioned listen for this standard event to detect the change.

Comment: Disregarding for a bit the using either/or `pushState`/`replaceStat`, both of them change the URL, and yes if `aura:locatonShange` detects on hash changes, the `forceCommunity:routeChange` should detect it, at least as per what the documentation states: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:routeChange/documentation